# openbox: disable "grab" window that moves together with mouse cursor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, gui, openbox

Normally in Openbox I can move windows around by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and grabbing the window with left mouse button.

But sometimes I accidentally "grab" a window and then it is stuck to my mouse without holding any keyboard key. The window moves with my mouse, and my mouse cursor changes to a "hand" cursors.

I can never find out how I did it, but it happens often enough, usually when I am doing something fast on the keyboard in the lower left corner around Alt and Ctrl and moving mouse simultaneously.

Anyway, how can I disable this?

Answer (score 0):

Open the openbox config file in a text editor:

```shell
vi ~/.config/openbox/rc.xml
```

Comment out the "Move" action section in the  block:

```xml
<!--
<mousebind button="Left" action="Drag">
    <action name="Move"/>
</mousebind>
-->
```

Save, exit and restart the service:

```shell
openbox --restart
```

If you want to disable <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left mouse button drag behaviour as well, you can comment out this section too.

```xml
<mousebind button="A-Left" action="Drag">
    <action name="Move"/>
</mousebind>
```